# How to safely keeping a user logged in

Tags: php, cookies

I was wondering how to keep a user logged in with cookies. I have this code:

```
setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+3600*24*7);
```

But I was told it wasn't safe because someone could get the session_id. So are they any other safe ways to keep a user logged in with php?

Comment: Why set the session cookie explicitly when PHP set that for you (when you start session) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think what you are asking is this:

http://us.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path

also check your particular settings